# How to log Ip address in wso2esb

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Hi am working with WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

I want to log client Ip address in the proxy, So i have set a property in my proxy as shown below

```
<property name="client_ip_address"
                   expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>

<log level="custom">
            <property name="client_ip_address" expression="get-property('client_ip_address')"/>

         </log>
```

When i run the proxy the log is generated as

```
[2015-09-05 12:21:19,582]  INFO - LogMediator client_ip_address = 127.0.0.1
```

It is not returning me the actual Ip address of the client instead it is returning me 127.0.0.1.

how can i get actual Ip address in the log.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the localhost address because you call the proxy from the same machine that WSO2 is running on.

Please call the proxy from a different machine than the machine running WSO2. Then you should see the effective IP address of the calling client.